# Getting a session_start warning on my site can someone give me a detailed solution on how to fix this

Tags: php, forms, session, session-cookies

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/home/content/58/7146558/tmp/sess_9ecd6l48tgu3kgmdottq5hm8v1, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home/content/58/7146558/html/upload/include/fgcontactform.php on line 63

Here is the code

```
class FGContactForm
{
var $receipients;
var $errors;
var $error_message;
var $name;
var $email;
var $message;
var $from_address;
var $form_random_key;
var $conditional_field;
var $arr_conditional_receipients;
var $fileupload_fields;
var $captcha_handler;

var $mailer;

function FGContactForm()
{
    $this->receipients = array();
    $this->errors = array();
    $this->form_random_key = 'HTgsjhartag';
    $this->conditional_field='';
    $this->arr_conditional_receipients=array();
    $this->fileupload_fields=array();

    $this->mailer = new PHPMailer();
    $this->mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
}

function EnableCaptcha($captcha_handler)
{
    $this->captcha_handler = $captcha_handler;
    session_start();
}

function AddRecipient($email,$name="")
{
    $this->mailer->AddAddress($email,$name);
}
```

Comment: Give permissions to the folder where you can write the session files. It is just because it is generating the file, but it is not been saved and this session is fetching from the file

Answer (score 0):

give permission chown -R apache:apache /path/to/session/folder

Comment: @user7436497 basically its giving permission to apache to right session in session folder. chmod 777 gives permission to everyone but apache:apache only gives permission to apache not to everyone.

Comment: @Anil_Dhiman so what would the code for that have to look like?

Answer (score -1):

Give permissions to the folder where you can write the session files. It is just because it is generating the file, but it is not been saved and this session is fetching from the file

Specifically

```
chmod 777
```

Comment: so what exactly would I have to put in the folder to make the warning disappear? @Jaymin Noob

Comment: You should *really* not allow everyone to write to the session directory. Even read access is problematic.

Comment: so what would you suggest I do @Peter

Comment: You give read and write permissions only to the user that runs the php process. It's often called www-data or apache, although looking at the filenames in your question I have no clue what's correct for you. If you are using a shared hoster you way want to get in touch with them.